# Tactic to partially compute goal in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have goal

```
quad X Y
```

, but I don't remember definition of "quad" and I don't want to start searching of its definition.

Is there a tactic that allow me rapidly substitute quad with its definition?

```
 Record quad (X Y:Type):= { x:X; y:Y}.
```

Or I have to remember and use

```
refine (@Build_quad _ _).
```

?

Comment: `constructor` should work is most cases. You  may also find `Hint Constructors` useful.

Comment: Btw, search in this case is not necessary, but it's rather simple: `Print quad.` will give you the desired information. If you're using ProofGeneral, you need to move the cursor (point) over the entity of interest and hit `C-c C-a C-p` and `Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your slightly mistaken, `Build_quad` is not the definition of `quad`, it is its constructor. It creates terms of type `quad`.
As @ejgallego said, you should use the `constructor` tactic in this situation.

Your goal wants you to provide a term of type `quad X Y`, and the only way to build such a term from scratch is to use the constructor `Build_quad` of type `forall X Y: Type, X -> Y -> quad X Y`.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: a less automated way would be to `apply Build_quad.` instead of using `constructor.`

Comment: Usually I use `split` for records.